# wsdl has no service element

Tags: java, web-services

I have to consume a WCF web service and was given a WSDL (external, so have no control on the WSDL). Inside the WSDL definitions I am not finding the service element which has the service, port and address elements. Is that normal not be present in a WSDL? Is this common for a WCF WSDL? I am trying to generate stubs for this using axis and am having issues.

```
<wsdl:definitions>
....
...
..

**<wsdl:service>
      <wsdl:port>
       <wsdl1:address/>
      </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>**

</wsdl:definitions>
```

The part between the asterisks is what is missing in the WSDL.

Did someone have an issue like this? Please let me know.

When generating stubs, I am getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:175)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No services found in the WSDL at file:/c:/work/xxx.wsdl with targetnamespace http://tempuri.org/
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.populateAllServices(WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:115)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:169)
        ... 2 more

I looked at the code WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java and it looks like this error occurs if axis does not find a service element.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Try to use a web service test tool like [Web Service Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/tutorials/WebServiceExplorer/WebServiceExplorer.html). If this tool can parse the WSDL and let you test it (as I think), then try to use a different tool like JBoss WS or NetBeans.

Comment: I used SOAPUI and the service tests okay. Unlike other WSDLs I used, when i import to SOAPUI, it does not automatically set the endpoint because it is missing. I add the .svc endpoint and it tests fine. I am not sure why the WSDL does not have the service element defined and is causing the stubs not to generate. Isn't service element mandatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found why this WSDL was missing the service tag, the original WSDL provided had an import which has the service element. I don't know if it is a correct way to do it or not, but the endpoint give to me to consume did not have it, I had to dig into other imported WSDLs to see that one of them had the service element.

Hope this helps someone.

I could not use a wsdl2java on the WSDL since there was no endpoint, do not know how to tell axis to look into the imported WSDLs for the service element though.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me with a similar import issue in a WSDL I was given.

Comment: Thank you for digging into this and sharing your discovery. I faced the same issue with https://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio.wsdl and your answer helped me stop wasting more time on wsdl2java