# Outlook.com WSDL has no service element

Tags: web-services, soap, outlook, wsdl

I'm trying to write a client for Outlook.com mail. I've successfully connected and authenticated, and downloaded the WSDL. However, the WSDL has no `service` element, which the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) requires.

I dutifully checked all the imports per the question "[wsdl has no service element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855765/wsdl-has-no-service-element)" even though they're called `messages.xsd` and `types.xsd`, and found no `service` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://code.google.com/p/imap2exchange/wiki/ExchangeWebServices) on Google Code describes the issue.

The `service` element is missing, presumably so they can distribute a single `Services.wsdl` that will work on all servers without having to customize it. I'm not sure of the reasoning.

The net effect is that you have to add the element yourself to the end of the file:

```
...

   <wsdl:service name="ExchangeServices">
     <wsdl:port name="ExchangeServicePort" binding="tns:ExchangeServiceBinding">
       <soap:address location="https://my.exchange.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"/>
     </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```